# How to page through post likes using FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get a list of all the likes for a given post. The problem I am having is that there isn't a timestamp field that I can use to "page" with and some posts have way more than 5000 likes(5000 being the most records you can get at one time)

How can I get all likes for posts with more than 5000 likes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = "POST_ID" LIMIT 5000 OFFSET [n * 5000 + 1]
```

Where `n` = 0, 1, 2, ... as needed until the query fails.

Comment: As far as I know, the maximum amount is 5000, and that's that - see penultimate paragraph in [this FB blogpost](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) : "the maximum number of results we will fetch ... is 5,000."

Comment: Actually the line is "the maximum number of results we will fetch **before running the visibility checks** is 5,000."

Comment: ... i.e. if you have selected any filters, you will get _less_ then 5000 results. Good point.